# Summing through list of jsons in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column with string entries with the following format (for example)

```
"[ { 'state' : 'CA', 'tax_amount' : 3},{ 'state' : 'AZ', 'tax_amount' : 4}]"
```

I want to sum through the tax_amounts in each entry to get a total tax amount for each row. How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What exactly is the output you want?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In this example, the output would be 7

Comment: What about multiple rows? Do you want the sum of tax_amount for each row? Or over all rows?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a scalar sub-query:

```
select t.*, 
       (select sum((item ->> 'tax_amount')::int) 
        from  jsonb_array_elements(t.the_column) as x(item)) as total_tax
from the_table t
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dfd088e79975827eba6d0bf9ec2aa2a6)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working - maybe this is another sql flavor? I am requesting for Postgres. the jsonb_array_elements function is not recognized.

Comment: @ilikemath3.14: `jsonb_array_elements()` is certainly valid. I just forgot to put the key name into single quotes.

Comment: I am getting the following error message: ERROR:  function jsonb_array_elements(json) does not exist. Edit: Figured it out - needed to cast to jsonb.

Comment: Can you explain the intuition behind the x(item) syntax? What is happening here?  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @ilikemath3.14: it's a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET()` function such as

```
WITH t(js) AS
(
 SELECT '[ { "state" : "CA", "tax_amount" : 3},
           { "state" : "AZ", "tax_amount" : 4}]'::JSONB
)
 SELECT SUM(tax_amount) AS total_tax_amount
   FROM t
  CROSS JOIN JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET(NULL::record,js )
             AS tab(state VARCHAR(10), tax_amount INT)

total_tax_amount
----------------
 7
```

after fixing the syntax of the JSON object by replacing *single-quotes* with *double-quotes*, and *double-quotes* wrapping up whole object with *single-quotes*.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7b44c2b115707cd8e2df1bcb0a129748)</kbd>

Comment: The string is a single entry, so it would be a total tax amount for each entry. Every entry has a string with multiple subentries in json form.

Comment: Isn't this result(7) that you want @ilikemath3.14 Can you explicitly express what else you want.as output ?